# Codeigniter : Sharing session variables across subdomains

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, subdomain

This question have been posted by many others, but I am not getting the exact answer I want.
I am using Codeigniter framework. I have mysite.com and m.mysite.com.
I want to share the session variable say `user_id` across the two.

I am setting the session using `$this->session->set_userdata()`. I have included the following code in config file :

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mysite.com');
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".mysite.com"
```

and in php.ini I have added `session.cookie_domain = .mysite.com`

Should this be done in both ? I mean in mysite.com and m.mysite.com.

Can some one please tell whats going wrong.

Comment: if you have 2 different code bases, then yes you will need to do it in in both places. make sure `$config['cookie_domain'] = ".mysite.com"` is set on both the main site and the mobile site.

Comment: Is there a need to do     session.cookie_domain = .mysite.com in php.ini if      $config['cookie_domain'] = ".mysite.com" is done in config ?

Comment: i've never had to do that with CI sessions, you should be ok leaving the PHP.ini file alone

Comment: Ok. Will give a try again and let you know :)

Comment: CI doesn't use php sessions... it uses its own session model. this is either database stored, or Cookie stored, thus the php ini directive won't make any difference to CI.

Comment: Is it possible to check this in localhost ?

Comment: you have to setup your hosts file to point both domains to 127.0.0.1 - and setup your apache environment with the servername for each domain to be picked up.

Comment: added 127.0.0.1  mysite.com m.mysite.com . Added the other code in config. Is it set now ?

Comment: try it, if you have vhosts setup on your apache, make sure the you've set `ServerName mysite.com` and `ServerAlias m.mysite.com`

Comment: Just forget about m.mysite.com. If I have mysite.com and I am dynamically creating sub-domains like paris.mysite.com or london.mysite.com , but only one code base... I want user to be logged in if he has done once. So session should be shared right?  For that the apart from changes in config file, is there any thing else to do  ?